# How to change list of inputs in a form to a list of links?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor

How can I make the following code be a list of links instead of a list of buttons?

```
@foreach (var item in @Model)
{ 
    using (Html.BeginForm(new { action = "GetL", controller = "L" }))
    {
         <input name="fileLocation" type="submit" value="@item" />
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, from `<input name="fileLocation" type="submit" value="@item" />` to `<a href='destinationURL'>Text</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[Html.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505070.aspx)** helper method to generate anchor tag

```
@foreach (var item in @Model)
{ 
   using (Html.BeginForm(new { action = "GetL", controller = "L" }))
   {
       @Html.ActionLink(item,"yourAction","YourController")           
   }
}
```

If you want to pass some parameters ( Ex : Id ) to the Action method, you can do it with  [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx) override

```
@Html.ActionLink(item,"yourAction","YourController",
                                                     new { @id="someVal"} ,null)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach (var item in @Model)
{ 
      using (Html.BeginForm(new { action = "GetL", controller = "L" }))
      {
           <a name="fileLocation" href="@item">@item</a>
      }
}
```

Comment: `href="@item"` is sure to be incorrect. Given the likely level of the OP, best to mention that they'll need to compose a legal url for this field.